# Why not have a separate SE site for discussing about the design decisions and capabilities of programming languages?

Tags: discussion, area-51, scope

Many times folks would like to ask questions such as "why is a language like that" or "is it the language scalable" or "what is the best domain of applicability" etc.

These questions are usually closed down for being too subjective for either Stack Overflow or Programmers.

I was thinking it'd be good to have a dedicated Stack Exchange site specifically to discuss the what's and why's of programming languages rather than specific coding-related questions.

What does the community think?

Comment: We could also add operating system or text editor recommendations to that site and call it Flamewars.SE.

Comment: hehe, @DanielBeck Going to consider adding that Area51 proposal, now!

Comment: BTW calling SE sites "forums" is always guaranteed to attract some downvotes. They are geared to Q & A not discussions.

Comment: @MartinSmith - updated! I was struggling with the choice of word. This is my first 'feedback' post you know :P

Comment: @DanielBeck - Yes, but sometimes comparative questions do make sense and probably need some 'expert opinion' to help clarify the need. I am specifically suggesting it be for the design considerations of the language and the like...

Comment: @Nupul: [voting works differently on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) - you can  (probably) read the downvotes as an indication that the community disagrees with your suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) The place to propose new sites is Area51.

2) Highly subjective questions don't work in the SE format, *at all*. It's not just a matter of community taste at stackoverflow.com.

3) I could conceive of a site where it was valid to ask 'why do languages use ++ for increment', with the proviso that the answers had to come from first-hand knowledge of the decision process (either via reference to published discussion of actual personal participation). Kind of the reverse of the wikipedia NOR policy. Betcha there would be a lot of unanswered questions on *that* score.

Comment: Hmmm...I see what you mean